# Google Sheets: Conditional Formatting of a Row -> Only Right or Left cells of a reference cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet and let's say that I have only one Row.

The range I use is A1 to A20 (20 cells).

What I would like to do is:

1) When I put a value "T" in one of the cells, then all the cells that are in the Right Hand will have a red background.

eg. if I put the value "T" to A5 then A6 to A20 will have red background.

2) Or the opposite for the left hand cells.

Thanks in advance for every reply.

Comment: What have you tried so far? what error did you have? Can you add here your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en) (*Format > Conditional Formatting*) to solve this without writing any code. Just select the range you want to conditionally format and set up the appropriate rules.

The conditional formatting tool is pretty straightforward to use. Based on your question, you would use the following rule (you will need to make 1 for each side):

- Format cells if... 'Text is exactly "T"'
- Formatting style... 'Red Background'
- Apply to range... pick the appropriate range

I also recommend using data validation with a dropdown (*Date > Validation > List of items*) on the controlling cell so that users can only select the values which you want (either T/F or /T).